# How to set StyleMask of NSWindow in external Application

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos

I would like to be able to manipulate an NSWindow from an external app. I know that I have to use the `ApplicationServices framework` but I am unsure of how to actually edit the setting of the window. How do I set the style mask of the external window? It might not be possible but I would love to know. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can modify the position and size of a window in an external application, but not the style mask.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Can I set the order of windows on the screen and the alpha of windows?